# How to access environment variables from a React lib project on NX?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, nomachine-nx

I created a global `.local.env` file and added a couple of variables. I'm able to access them from `apps/my-app` but not from `libs/my-lib`. Is there any way to do it?